# Inserting into linked list alphabetically

Tags: c, list, struct, linked-list, alphabetical

I've been asked to insert into a linked list alphabetically in C, the problem is I can't seem to actually get the list in alphabetical order. I think there may be some problems with my linked list code. I've been working on this for quite a few days now and I just can't seem to get my head around it. Any help is appreciated :)

ps precedes is just a function that tells you if the current students name should come before the other name in question. it works as a boolean but instead of true and false you have 1 and 0.

```
Student* insert(Student* student, Student* list)
{
    Student* current;

    if (list == NULL || (precedes(student->name, list->name) > 0)) {
        student->next = list;
        list = student;
    } else {
        current = list;
        while(current->next != NULL && (precedes(current->name, student->name) > 0)) {
            current= current->next;
        }
        student->next = current->next;
        current->next = student;

    }
    return list;
}
```

Comment: In C, zero is false, and nonzero is true, and all logical expressions evaluate to `0` or `1`. For example, `(2 > 3)` is equal to `1`, and `(-5 > -4)` is equal to `0`. So, you can just use `precedes(before, after)` as a logical expression, no need to compare its return value. As to your problem, consider whether you should be comparing the name on the current node, or the next node, against the name to be inserted.

Comment: @NominalAnimal you are a legend.

Comment: :)  When you fix your problem, you can consider self-answering it. Explaining exactly what went wrong, and how you fixed it, is not only useful for others later encountering a similar issue and reading your question and answer, but it also helps you "organize" your thoughts about it: that in turn will help you solve similar types of problems in the future. At least for me, it has turned out to be very effective.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I fixed it with the help of NominalAnimal.

What happened was in this line

```
while(current->next != NULL && (precedes(current->name, student->name) > 0)) {
```

I should've been comparing the student's name to next student in the list, not the current one.

Cheers